# Trouble Retrieving ParseFile for ParseUser

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

For my ParseUsers, there is a column named "profilePicture" of type ParseFile, and given a user I try to retrieve the ParseFile and convert it to Bitmap with the following code:

```
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 4;
    Bitmap image = null;

    ParseFile profilePicture = user.getParseFile("profilePicture");
    System.out.println("DATA: " + profilePicture.isDataAvailable());

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = profilePicture.getDataStream();
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
```

Getting the ParseFile works fine, but every single time isDataAvailable() will return false, even though I manually check the column to ensure that there is an image file in the "profilePicture" column for that particular user. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.getDataInBackground` method and decode your file in the `done()` method

```
 profilePicture.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(byte[] data, ParseException e) {
       // Do your magic
    }
 });
```

Comment: I want to be able to display the picture during the onCreate() stage of the activity, but if I use getDataInBackground the picture will only be retrieved after onCreate() finishes, and if I try to use getData the info the data is not yet available. Any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: The whole idea is not to block your onCreate(). Why do you think you must have the image before onCreate() finishes?

Comment: Because I want all the user information to be readily displayed when the activity becomes visible to the user, which includes the user's profile picture.

Comment: Did you try .getData() then? It should block until file is fetched.